# Shimano Claris FH-2400 Rear Hub Dimensions

Tags: hub, wheel-building

I would like to purchase this hub, rim and suitable spokes, but I am not able to find dimensions of this hub necessary to calculate spoke size. I have checked usual places where such information can be found, but without success.

Does anyone own this hub, and has taken its measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details found here: http://productinfo.shimano.com/specifications.html

```
Spoke Hole P.C.D. Left/Right (mm) 45
Flange distance (mm) 57.9
Dish (mm) 8.4
```

Based on these figures, I would calculate the following values for your chosen Spoke Length Calculator:

```
Centreline to Left flange: 37.35mm
Centreline to Right flange: 20.55
```

Spoke hole diameter is not given.